# My moq test for unit of work doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, moq

I have the controler which have the method `GetAll` (show all creams)

```
public class AdminController : Controller
{
    private readonly ICreamUOW creamUOW;

    public AdminController( ICreamUOW creamUOW)
    {
        this.creamUOW = creamUOW;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]
    public PartialViewResult TableCreams()
    {
        return PartialView(creamUOW.Creams.GetAll.ToList());
    }
}
```

I realize the **Unit of Work** pattern for my repositories

```
public class CreamUOW : ICreamUOW
{
    private readonly CreamEFDbContext contextDb;
    private CreamRepository creamRepository;

    public CreamUOW()
    {
        this.contextDb = new CreamEFDbContext();
    }

    //properties
    public CreamRepository Creams
    {
        get
        {
            if (creamRepository == null)
                creamRepository = new CreamRepository(contextDb);
            return creamRepository;
        }
    }
}
```

and his interface

```
public interface ICreamUOW : IDisposable
{
    CreamRepository Creams { get; }
}
```

I bind this class and interface by ninject IoC

```
 kernel.Bind<ICreamUOW>().To<CreamUOW>();
```

*(I show just the methods and property where I have the problem, I realize a dispose method in project, but it doesn't important now)*

my generic repository interface

```
public interface ICreamRepository<T> where T : class
{
    //property
    IEnumerable<T> GetAll { get; }
}
```

and his realization

```
public class CreamRepository : ICreamRepository<CreamModel>
{
    private CreamEFDbContext context;

    public CreamRepository(CreamEFDbContext dbContext)
    {
        context = dbContext;
    }

    public IEnumerable<CreamModel> GetAll
    {
        get { return context.CreamModels.Include(x => x.CreamTypeModel); }
    }
}
```

I try to make the test but it doesn't work

```
[TestMethod]
    public void TableCreamContainCreams()
    {
        //arrange
        List<CreamModel> creams = new List<CreamModel>()
        {
            new CreamModel () { Id = 1, Name = "Test te1", Description = "1" },
            new CreamModel () { Id = 2, Name = "Test te2", Description = "2" }
        };

        private Mock<ICreamUOW> mockCreamUOW = new Mock<ICreamUOW>();
        mockCreamUOW.Setup(uow => uow.Creams.GetAll).Returns(creams.ToList());

        AdminController controller = new AdminController(null, null, mockCreamUOW.Object);

        //action
        PartialViewResult resultView = controller.TableCreams();

        //assert
        Assert.AreEqual(((List<CreamModel>)resultView.Model).Count(), 2);
        Assert.IsTrue(((List<CreamModel>)resultView.Model).Count(p => p.Description == "1") == 1);
    }
```

I take  the

> Message: Test method UnitTests.TestAdminController.TableCreamContainCreams threw exception: 
>   System.NotSupportedException: Invalid setup on a non-virtual (overridable in VB) member: uow => uow.Creams.GetAll

What it mean and how write the right test ? Can anybody help?

Comment: You can only mock/setup methods in the type you mock. If you create a mock for ICreamUOW you can setup Creams. If you want to setup GetAll() you must create a mock of ICreamRepository instead. If you find yourself mocking *two* layers, you’re probably doing something wrong in your tests - the typical scenario is you’re testing layer A (only), and it calls layer B, but you don’t want to use a “real” layer B (as perhaps it sends an email, or isn’t deterministic, etc), so you mock that layer instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only mock interfaces and virtual methods with Moq.

I think we have 2 options.

**One** is to add `virtual` keyword to `GetAll` property of `CreamRepository`.

```
public virtual IEnumerable<CreamModel> GetAll
{
    get
    {
        return context.CreamModels.Include(a => a.CreamTypeModel);
    }
}
```

Then add another **Mock** of **CreamRepository** in your unit test.

```
// A mock of CreamRepository, with null passed in because the constructor wants it
Mock<CreamRepository> mockCreamRepository = new Mock<CreamRepository>(null);

// which will return fake data
mockCreamRepository.Setup(mcr => mcr.GetAll).Returns(creams);

// Calling Creams on Mock UOW will give us Mock CreamRepository
// which will in turn give us the fake data if its GetAll is called. 
mockCreamUOW.Setup(uow => uow.Creams).Returns(mockCreamRepository.Object);
```

**Two** is make the `GetAll` method of `ICreamUOW` and `CreamUOW` return `ICreamRepository<CreamModel>`

```
public class CreamUOW : ICreamUOW
{
    // No changes to the rest of your code
    public ICreamRepository<CreamModel> Creams
    {
    }
}

public interface ICreamUOW : IDisposable
{
    // So your interface will be
    ICreamRepository<CreamModel> Creams { get; }
}
```

And your unit test

```
// Now we are mocking an interface instead of a concrete class like above
Mock<ICreamRepository<CreamModel>> mockCreamRepository = new Mock<ICreamRepository<CreamModel>>();
// The rest is the same
mockCreamRepository.Setup(mcr => mcr.GetAll).Returns(creams);
mockCreamUOW.Setup(uow => uow.Creams).Returns(mockCreamRepository.Object);
```

However, as @sellotape pointed out and I'm not familiar with your implementation of UOW and Repository, there must be something wrong because if we are testing a piece of code that calls layer A, which will then call layer B, we should only need to mock layer A.

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: thank you, the key word `virtual` help. However may be better make two test for the both layer? how you think? Because I don't think that is good case for me make all the another methods and properties virtual.

Comment: If that's the case ( I think the same too, making them all virtual isn't always desirable ) then you should go with option two.

Comment: well I try to do that, if i can't I will make a question, because it's my first step to mocking. But anyway thank you!)